# How to decrease the speed of Video using cv2.VideoWriter()?

Tags: opencv, frame-rate

I'm trying to write a video using cv2.VideoWriter() and I defined the following function.
the point is that when I change the fps=30 to 20 or any other value, there is no change in the output and the video play speed is higher than what I would like to have.

```py
def video_Writer(images_path_read, output_vid_path, fps=30):

    '''
    parameters:
        - images_path_read - the path containing images to be combined and make a video
        - output_vid_path - the path and file name of output video (must include .mp4)
    method:
        - the function get the images path, read the sorted images and make a video according
        to the first image size.

    '''

    dir_images_list = os.listdir(images_path_read)
    dir_images_list = natsorted(dir_images_list)

    # get the size of the first image
    fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    img_0 = cv2.imread(images_path_read + dir_images_list[0])

    # find the image shape
    size = (img_0.shape[1], img_0.shape[0])

    # Creating VideoWriter Object and open it to start in the loop
    vid_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_vid_path, fourcc, fps, size)
    vid_writer.open(output_vid_path, fourcc, fps, size)

    for image in dir_images_list:
        # Reading the images from the path folder
        img = cv2.imread(images_path_read + image)
        
        # Checking the size of frames
        if size[0] != img.shape[1] or size[1] != img.shape[0]:
            img = resize(img, size)
            print('Resizing Happend')
        # Adding images to Video
        vid_writer.write(img)
    #     print(image)

    # Releasing VideoWriter Object
    vid_writer.release()
```

Please help me to find out the reason.
Thanks

Comment: Can you change to 1 fps and verify that there is still no difference in playback speed? How do you play the videos (which video player application)?

Comment: Thank you. I changed fps to 1 and then 10 but nothing changed. Then I changed it to 1.0 and then 10.0 and it worked. So I have to set the fps as a float not int. Thanks again.